# Sql Select query while inserting more data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new in sql server. I have a simple question related to select query.

For example, Consider I have more then 10000 values and I am inserting those value into table and assume that 2000 rows are inserted and I have an query select * from table.

So do select query display those 2000 rows which is inserted?

Comment: If table was empty before, then yes, but if you had previously inserted some rows you will get more.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the most recent 2000 rows

And I am assuming that you have a integer primary key

```
Select Top 2000 *
From YourTable
Order By [primary key] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
Select top 2000 *
from table
```